# Is there a way of getting Excel to report on whether or not something is overdue?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Tracking work progress on project deliverables and want to colour code which dates are overdue, coming due, or on track.

I tried =IF(A2<TODAY(),"Overdue","Not due") //where A2 had the date it was due

Which worked, but only entered text. I've tried conditional formatting rule saying any cell contains a value < TODAY() but that didn't do anything, then I tried anchoring TODAY() in a cell for reference, but still no luck. (i.e. conditional formatting, any cell contains a value less than $J2)

Comment: so you put `=TODAY()` in `J2`?  Then you should probably need `$J$2` not `$J2`

Comment: Enter the formula in conditional formatting such that the formula returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  ie `=A2<TODAY()`.  It is my understanding that the formula entered has to start with `=`.  If you got back to edit the formula and you see excel added some quotes, delete the quotes and make sure the formula stats with `=`.

Answer (score 0):

### ♣ SOLVED  3 possible ways ♣

1. Conditional formatting (proposed approach)

- Select range you're interested in
- Press Conditional Format toolbox
- See screenshots below for illustration of what after that

[image: After applying conditional to C2: c9]

[image: Rules]

[image: Edit a rule]

[image: Specifying cell format for when rule is 'true' format for that rule]

### Other methods

(This section may/not be of interest...but just in case it is...)

2. Cell Format

You can change custom formats to return a variety of colours:

e.g. Following will display blue whenever the condition 'delivery date < due date; red if it occurs after the delivery date, and pink on the day..

```
[Blue][<44333]ddd-dd mmm;[Red][>44333]ddd-dd-mmm;[Magenta]ddd-dd mmm
```

i.e. [Colour][]followed by desired dd-mm/yyyy cell format, e.g.

use:

```
cell.font.Color = -16776961`
```

Shortcomings: updating due date does not seem straight forar

---

3. VB code

Something along the lines of ....

[image]
Custom format:

```
[Blue][<44333]ddd-dd mmm;[Red][>44333]ddd-dd-mmm;[Magenta]ddd-dd mmm
```

For Each cell In Cells:
cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

'source: https://excelatfinance.com/xlf/xlf-colors-1.php

- 'Black: RGB(0,0,0)
- 'White: RGB(255,255,255)
- 'Red: RGB(255,0,0)
- 'Green: RGB(0,255,0)
- 'Blue: RGB(0,0,255)
- 'Yellow: RGB(255,255,0)
- 'Magenta: RGB(255,0,255)
- 'Cyan: RGB(0,255,255)

Source: [here](https://excelatfinance.com/xlf/xlf-colors-1.php).